# C# with metro, is the sealed keyword an absolute requirement?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro

I know that you can write metro applications in c#. My question is if the sealed keyword is required for every class. I tried to compile a metro application and I removed the sealed keyword from the class. It still compiled.

So how is the sealed keyword exactly used in metro applications and C#. What's the reason behind it. Is it only required if you want the classes to be visible in another language other than a .net language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is an absolute requirement.  But only for *certain* classes, the kind that you expose to other languages that run on WinRT.  In other words, when you create your own component that you want, say, Javascript or C++ to use as well.

There are a number of restrictions on such classes, the technical reason for it is that WinRT runs on top of COM and COM does not support implementation inheritance.  It *looks* like it does, like the XAML classes appear to use inheritance.  But that's an illusion created by the language projection that's built into the CLR.  That illusion doesn't work both ways.

In general, it is fairly rare to want to do this and you'll need to keep several restrictions in mind.  For your own C# classes, the ones you write to implement your own Store app there are no such restrictions and *sealed* is not a requirement.

Comment: So I can make my own c# unsealed classes in various assemblies and successfully refer them in a C# metro project? What about windows phone support. Can I make reusable C# assemblies for windows phone too that include classes which aren't sealed?